# Search for duplicates - result missing

Tags: bug

Wanting to close vote a question for being a duplicate of the well-known [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I searched in the closure dialog for `"boots to a black screen"` - in vain, the desired result didn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

While typing my question I remembered having talked about delimiters in searches before - and indeed the search for `"boot to a black screen,"` gave the expected result.

Still: this is probably a bug.

Comment: The whole search function in the close vote dialog is a giant bug :P